# FreeBSD Reinstall postfix with mysql support

Tags: mysql, postfix, smtp, reinstall

I have installed postfix using the ports tree without making modifications to anything.
In my main.cf file i can't specify any 'Mysql:/' arguments because postfix does not have mysql support. Now i want to reinstall postfix with mysql support.

i have tried the following:

```
make -f Makefile.init makefiles \
'CCARGS=-DHAS_MYSQL -I/usr/local/mysql/include' \
'AUXLIBS_MYSQL=-L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -lz -lm'
```

This command outputs 'make: cannot open Makefile.init.'

And when i try to make in custom 'Make' file with this code:

```
    make makefiles \ 
CCARGS="-DHAS_MYSQL -I/usr/include/mysql \
AUXLIBS="-L/usr/lib/mysql/ -lmysqlclient \
```

Freebsd outputs: 'don't know how to make makefiles. Stop'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: If you're looking for the recently released Postfix 3.0 series, you should substitute `mail/postfix-current` for `mail/postfix` below.

You may manually set configuration options when using the ports tree, but you don't have to. If you installed postfix via pkg, run `pkg delete postfix` with root privileges. If you installed via local ports tree compilation, do:

```
cd /usr/ports/mail/postfix
make deinstall
```

If your ports tree is not located at `/usr/ports`, substitute the path as necessary.

To compile with MySQL support:

```
cd /usr/ports/mail/postfix
make config
```

Then select the 'MYSQL' option and any others you'd like, and

```
make install clean
```

If you'd prefer not to use the interactive options, follow the directions [here](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports-announce/2013-June/000062.html) instead.

FreeBSD's extensive [handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/index.html) is one of its best features (which is saying a lot, because there are a lot of good things to find in FreeBSD. I would suggest reading through the chapter on [ports](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports.html).

Good Luck!